# Question about the tenses

Tags: future-tense, future-time

Which form is better with the "**this week**, **this month**, and **this year**"?

I want to say about a shop.

> A shop closes  [this week | this month | this year].
>
> A shop is going to be closed  [this week | this month | this year].
>
> A shop will be closed [this week | this month | this year].

Which form should I choose?

Comment: Is the shop closing down permanently? Is it closing temporarily to be painted? Does it always close at a certain time or for certain holidays?

Answer (score 2):

When we want to express scheduled events in the near future we may say:
    -A shop closes [this week / this month / this year].

When we want to express that some events will happen in the near future we may say:
    -A shop is going to be closed [this week / this month / this year].

When we plan, intend to do something in the future we may say:
    -A shop will be closed [this week / this month / this year].

So, all constructions you are asking about are grammatically correct and can be used.

Both "will" and "be going to" can express the idea of a general prediction about the future. Predictions are guesses about what might happen in the future.

The verb to close may be used either active or passive: “a shop closes” or “a shop is closed”.

Answer (score 0):

If the action ( the closing of the shop) has already been decided, planned to happen, I would choose = "The shop is going to be closed this week/month/year."However, if you have made an on-the spot decision, then you can use the future simple. example: "I  have just decided that the shop will be closed this week". As for the present tense, I don't think I would use it in this situation. For scheduled events(timetables) we could say: "The plane leaves every morning at eight". " A bus runs every five minutes".